# Most secure way to authenticate VPN via script for connection from remote server to home network?

Tags: vpn, account-security

What is the most secure way to automatically connect my remote server via OpenVPN to my home network for running a script?

The plan is I want to automatically backup some folders to my Synology NAS at certain times. I assume saving the VPN username and password in a file is one of the worst ways, but on the other hand PKA is basically the same, since if someone gets access to my server, they either have username and password or my private key? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: keys are the way to go

Comment: Given that your threat scenario involves somebody getting access to the server: Are you sure that it is even a good idea that a **potentially compromised** server can authenticate successfully against the home network?

Comment: @sysadt are you limited to using OpenVPN? could your home server come in via `ssh`, with authorised key, and execute whatever commands you like.. eg. one such solution I've used in the past is to `gzip | gpg2` (or `gzip | openssl`) backup files into a directory that is accessible via https, then launched a second process to obtain the backup file - all of this would be driven by your home server (ie. 'pull' as distinct from 'push')